# Ebay Java SDK with JBoss - Interceptor for eBayAPIInterfaceService has thrown exception,unwinding now:java.lang.RuntimeException:Couldn't parse stream

Tags: servlets, jboss, ebay-api

I am creating a web application using Ebay Java SDK. I have created a code to get session id using credentials. now it is working file if I run the java file. but if I want to call it from Servlet and deploy it on JBoss, then the same method stop working and give the parse stream exception nested by character conversion.

Regarding code following is the code I am using.

```
ApiContext apiContext = new ApiContext();
ApiCredential cred = apiContext.getApiCredential();
ApiAccount apiAccount = cred.getApiAccount();
apiAccount.setApplication(LabelConstants.PROD_APP_ID);
apiAccount.setCertificate(LabelConstants.PROD_CERT_ID);
apiAccount.setDeveloper(LabelConstants.PROD_DEV_ID);
apiContext.setApiServerUrl(LabelConstants.PROD_API_URL);
apiContext.setRuName(LabelConstants.PROD_RU_NAME);

GetSessionIDCall gsic = new GetSessionIDCall(apiContext);
gsic.setRuName(apiContext.getRuName());

try {
    sessionId = gsic.getSessionID();
    System.out.println(sessionId);
} catch (ApiException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SdkException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
17:22:23,255 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Interceptor for {urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}eBayAPIInterfaceService#{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}GetSessionID has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't parse stream.
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1178)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:104)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:795)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1626)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1493)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1401)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:648)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:461)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:364)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:317)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.getSessionID(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at com.ebay.sdk.ApiCall.callSOAP(Unknown Source) [ebaysdkcore.jar:]
at com.ebay.sdk.ApiCall.executeByApiName(Unknown Source) [ebaysdkcore.jar:]
at com.ebay.sdk.ApiCall.execute(Unknown Source) [ebaysdkcore.jar:]
at com.ebay.sdk.call.GetSessionIDCall.getSessionID(GetSessionIDCall.java:76) [ebaycalls.jar:]
at com.ba.label.conf.GetApiContext.getSessionId(GetApiContext.java:73) [classes:]
at com.ba.label.servlet.AuthServlet.doGet(AuthServlet.java:43) [classes:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)
at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:536)
at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:585)
at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:610)
at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:316)
at __redirected.__XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(__XMLInputFactory.java:139) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1176)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidInitial(UTF8Reader.java:303)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:189)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.initialLoad(ReaderBootstrapper.java:250)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.bootstrapInput(ReaderBootstrapper.java:133)
at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:531)
... 47 more
```

Can anyone explain how can I run the Ebay SDK on Servlet and container?

Comment: atleast inform me the way for that i get minus 1 for this question

Comment: You don't show any code, just the StackTrace. We can't help you without code.

Comment: code added. I thought some body else has this problem as well. I have clearly mentioned that same code is running in java but not running when i use web container. any how now i have added the code as well.

Comment: @Charlie: Huh? Why should the OP show code if the stack trace alone already indicates that no single line of OP's own code is causing the problem? How should the OP know which code exactly he has to show? Why didn't you tell which code exactly the OP has to show? Please stop posting confusing nonsense comments as long as you're incapable of reading stack traces.

Comment: @BalusC The OP wanted to know why he had downvotes, and I think it was because of that.

Comment: @Charlie: nope, because it was tagged `[java]` which attracted nitwits knowing absolutely nothing about the Java EE related matter and therefore make severe misassumptions or even post completely irrelevant comments. I already removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

```
yourcall.setEnableCompression(false);
```

worked for me

Comment: i did that as well because lot of sites has refer that but of no use. Thanks for sharing your solution.